# Can´t boot Ubuntu 16.04 after upgrade

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 16.04

Ubuntu propose upgrade. I accepted. While installing packages it stops (a lot of time) with a message about conflict with TrueTypeFonts and something else about Windows OS.
Now GRUB allows choose OS. But Ubuntu don´t starts. Last message is about loading system in RAM. I can initiate in recovery mode, login with user+password. In a command line without net connection.
I had tried with a bootable USB stick, but it don´t boot. How can i boot the system without erase user documents?
Espero no haber ofendido demasiado al lector con mi torpe inglés.

Answer (score -1):

if you have a seperate space for /home u can reinstall ubuntu without loss any data in users! but carefull : you must use exactly previous username in install steps.

otherwise login in recovery mode and use update-grub2 command and write demsg output here.

Comment: Thnks. Ubuntu responds in spanish. triing to translate:

Comment: after update_grub2  <br> Not allowed GRUB_TIMEOUT value different to zero  <br> Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-65-generic  <br> Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-65-generic  <br> ....other older version...  <br> Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf  <br> Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin  <br> Found in WindowsVista (loader) in /dev/sda1  <br> done